# Aggregate function that append columns values of each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a similar table to this:

```
Id     Name    CommitDate  Commits
------ ------- ----------- --------
1      Ahmed   2018-07-05  2
1      Ahmed   2018-07-07  6
```

I need this output:

```
Id     Name    Summary
------ ------- -------------------------------------------------
1      Ahmed   2 commits on 2018-07-05\n 6 commits on 2018-07-07
```

Actually, I stopped at this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, '' AS Summary  FROM Commits
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

and couldn't continue, as every `GROUP BY` clause I used before came with a simple aggregate function, I'm unable to figure out if there is an aggregate function that can append grouped columns together!

Comment: if you use SQL Server 2017, then you may use STRING_AGG: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 or later, you can use [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select  id
,       name
,       string_agg(cast(commits as nvarchar(5)) + ' commits on ' + 
                   convert(nvarchar(10), commitdate, 120), char(10)) + char(10)
from    commits
group by
        id
,       name
```

You can express newline in SQL Server like `char(10)`, or for a linefeed plus newline, `char(13) + char(10)`.  The `120` style [converts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) a `datetime` to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

[Working example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9028/5/0)